# How to clip a image using 4 corner(x,y) in imagemagick C#

Tags: c#, imagemagick, clipping

I am using afroge previously to clip image using 4 corners of the image like below and it works fine and only problem with Aforge is not able to handle large images like 40000 X 34000 using bitmap, so I want to check imageMagick to crop using 4 corner, but it seems it accepts x,y and width and height of the image to crop, but this will not work if the image is tilted or not straight.

I have tried ImageMagick using below code, but it takes only one x,y location and height and width, which will provide wrong clipped image

```
Point location = new Point();
location.X = topleft.X;
location.Y = topleft.Y;        
Size ze = new Size();
ze.Height = width;
ze.Height = height;
Rectangle rt = new Rectangle(location, ze);
MagickGeometry mgeomentory = new MagickGeometry(rt);
originalImage.Crop(mgeomentory);
```

aforge code - existing code - working perfectly

```
List<AForge.IntPoint> corners = new List<AForge.IntPoint>();
corners.Add(new AForge.IntPoint(topleft.X, topleft.Y));
corners.Add(new AForge.IntPoint(topright.X, topright.Y));
corners.Add(new AForge.IntPoint(bottomright.X, bottomright.Y));
corners.Add(new AForge.IntPoint(bottomleft.X, bottomleft.Y));

SimpleQuadrilateralTransformation filter = new 
SimpleQuadrilateralTransformation(corners, width, height);
Bitmap newImage = filter.Apply(originalImage);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've rewritten jcupitt's example code in C#. This example uses [net-vips](https://github.com/kleisauke/net-vips/), the C# binding for [libvips](https://libvips.github.io/libvips/).

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Length != 8)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
            "Usage: [input] [output] " +
            "[topLeftX] [topLeftY] " +
            "[topRightX] [topRightY] " +
            "[bottomRightX] [bottomRightY]");
        return;
    }

    Image image = Image.NewFromFile(args[0]);
    string outFilename = args[1];
    int topLeftX = int.Parse(args[2]);
    int topLeftY = int.Parse(args[3]);
    int topRightX = int.Parse(args[4]);
    int topRightY = int.Parse(args[5]);
    int bottomRightX = int.Parse(args[6]);
    int bottomRightY = int.Parse(args[7]);

    // the angle the top edge is rotated by
    int dx = topRightX - topLeftX;
    int dy = topRightY - topLeftY;
    double angle = (180 / Math.PI) * Math.Atan2(dx, dy);
    if (angle < -45 || angle >= 45)
    {
        angle = 90 - angle;
    }

    // therefore the angle to rotate by to get it straight
    angle = -angle;

    image = image.Rotate(angle);

    // the new position of the rectangle in the rotated image
    double radians = (Math.PI * angle) / 180.0;
    double c = Math.Cos(radians);
    double s = Math.Sin(radians);

    int left = Convert.ToInt32(topLeftX * c - topLeftY * s);
    int top = Convert.ToInt32(topLeftX * s + topLeftY * c);
    int width = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(topRightX - topLeftX, 2) +
                                          Math.Pow(topRightY - topLeftY, 2)));
    int height = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(topRightX - bottomRightX, 2) +
                                           Math.Pow(topRightY - bottomRightY, 2)));

    // after a rotate, the new position of the origin is given by .Xoffset, .Yoffset
    Image tile = image.Crop(left + image.Xoffset, top + image.Yoffset, width, height);

    tile.WriteToFile(outFilename);
}
```

Note that if you need OpenSlide support on Windows, you'll have to use the libvips `-all` distribution. For security reasons, NetVips only bundles the `-web` libvips x86/x64 distribution. See [here](https://github.com/kleisauke/net-vips/issues/18#issuecomment-427906129) for a complete tutorial.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, I don't know how you do it. but it is lightning fast.... :)

Comment: After cropping image I want to read RGB values of whole image for further processing, when I try using tile.Getpoint(x, y) for the image width * height. it is taking huge time for 53657*4973 dimension. is there any way to speed up??

Comment: Yes, `GetPoint` is only useful for reading single points. If you want to make a large memory array, use `WriteToMemory`:  https://kleisauke.github.io/net-vips/api/NetVips.Image.html#NetVips_Image_WriteToMemory

Comment: Or perhaps you can do your further processing in net-vips? It would probably be easier, and would execute much more quickly. What do you need to do?

Comment: We need to provide RGB color information to another API which is application specific.

Comment: @jcupitt When I applied resize it show exception "unable to call resize", By the what is scale factor, If I want to resize orginal image from 3100*4100 to 3300(W)*4500(H), I see Reduce operation is there anything like increase size?

Comment: You give `Resize` a ratio, so `2` for double in size, `0.5` for halve in size. It then runs the correct series of operations for you.

Comment: @kleisauke, This approach works only for the image clipping for Top and bottom are same, otherwise at the bottom it clipping at the wrong point. At crop image in netvips support based on TopRight, TopLeft and width and height, where as TopWidth and bottomwidth are same in my image cropping and it fails

Answer (score 2):

Convert your four corners (assuming a non-rotated rectangle) to WxH+X+Y and then use Imagemagick.

If we assume the 4 points are arranged clockwise from the top-left as (top-left, top-right, bottom-right, bottom-left), then mathematically we would compute:

```
W=(top-right-x - top-left-x)
H=(bottom-left-y -top-left-y)
X=top-left-x
Y=top-left-y
```

Then in Imagemagick 6 command line:

```
convert image -crop WxH+X+Y +repage croppedimage
```

If I misunderstand your issue, please clarify.

ADDITION:

If you have a rotated rectangle defined by the 4 points, then you can compute the bounding box and convert that to WxH+X+Y to crop with the command above.

To do that get the min-x, min-y, max-x, max-y from your 4 points. Then

```
W=(max-x - min-x)
H=(max-y - min-y)
X=min-x
Y=min-y
```

Comment: This will not work, because for example topleft(4015, 4452) and topright(4444,4458) , if you see y there is a difference , we cannot use X,Y , width and height directly. we need to use 4 corner as mentioned in my example

Comment: `@Jey`. You asked about using Imagemagick, unless I misunderstood your question. I have shown how to convert 4 corners to WxH+X+Y, which is the only way Imagemagick crop works. Why is that not acceptable to do the computations and use WxH+X+Y. The computations are trivial. You can arrange your 4 coordinates into the arrangement that I proposed. Please clarify why this is not possible for you. You can process using Magick.NET.

Comment: Is the issue that you have a rotated rectangle? Perhaps a picture or diagram would help us understand better what you want to do. If the rectangle is rotated, then you could find the bounding box from the 4 points and use that to get the WxH+X+Y for cropping with Imagemagick. Or perhaps `jcupitt` has an adequate solution coded for you below.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [net-vips](https://github.com/kleisauke/net-vips), the C# binding for [libvips](https://jcupitt.github.io/libvips/). It's a lazy, streaming, demand-driven image processing library, so it can do operations like this without needing to load the whole image.

There isn't an operation that can directly do an angled crop, but it's easy to make one yourself with a little trig.

For example, using the libvips binding for Python (sorry, I don't have C# installed here, but the API is the same):

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
import math
import pyvips

image = pyvips.Image.new_from_file(sys.argv[1])
out_filename = sys.argv[2]
top_left_x = int(sys.argv[3])
top_left_y = int(sys.argv[4])
top_right_x = int(sys.argv[5])
top_right_y = int(sys.argv[6])
bottom_right_x = int(sys.argv[7])
bottom_right_y = int(sys.argv[8])

# the angle the top edge is rotated by
dx = top_right_x - top_left_x
dy = top_right_y - top_left_y
angle = math.degrees(math.atan2(dx, dy))
if angle < -45 or angle >= 45:
    angle = 90 - angle

# therefore the angle to rotate by to get it straight
angle = -angle

image = image.rotate(angle)

# the new position of the rectangle in the rotated image
c = math.cos(math.radians(angle))
s = math.sin(math.radians(angle))
left = top_left_x * c - top_left_y * s
top = top_left_x * s + top_left_y * c
width = math.hypot(top_right_x - top_left_x, top_right_y - top_left_y)
height = math.hypot(top_right_x - bottom_right_x, top_right_y - bottom_right_y)

# after a rotate, the new position of the origin is given by .xoffset, .yoffset
tile = image.crop(left + image.xoffset, top + image.yoffset, width, height)

tile.write_to_file(out_filename)
```

I can run it like this on a huge image:

```
$ vipsheader ~/pics/openslide/bild.ndpi 
/home/john/pics/openslide/bild.ndpi: 126976x98304 uchar, 4 bands, rgb, openslideload
$ time ./angled_crop.py ~/pics/openslide/bild.ndpi x.jpg 680 760 936 836 484 1552
real    0m0.304s
user    0m0.388s
sys 0m0.040s
```

So it takes 0.3s to crop a small angled area from a 127000 x 98000 pixel image.

Openslide images are (approximately) tiled tiff, so it only needs to decode the parts of the input image necessary to make the output.

It'll work on untiled images too, though it will need to decode the whole image first. It'll decode to memory for images under 100mb, and to a temporary file otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I also needed to remove any EXIF Flip flags before calling Crop()

(Sorry POC code)

```
using (var srcImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("myImage.png"))
{
      rotationFixedImage = "myFixedImage.png";
      NormalizeOrientation(srcImage);
      srcImage.Save(rotationFixedImage);
}
            
...
            
using (var srcImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(rotationFixedImage))
{                        
    WriteCroppedImageFile(rotationFixedImage, "newFileName.png", x1, x2, y1, y2);                          
}
            
...

public void WriteCroppedImageFile(string sourceImagefilePath, string croppedImageFilePath, int cropX1, int cropX2, int cropY1, int cropY2)
{
    var geo = new ImageMagick.MagickGeometry(cropX1, cropY1, cropX2 - cropX1, cropY2 - cropY1);
    using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage(sourceImagefilePath))
    {
        image.Crop(geo); // Crop the image and height. 
        image.Quality = 75; // This is the Compression level.
        image.Write(croppedImageFilePath); 
    }
}

...

public void NormalizeOrientation(System.Drawing.Image image)
{
    int ExifOrientationTagId = 0x112;
    if (Array.IndexOf(image.PropertyIdList, ExifOrientationTagId) > -1)
    {
        int orientation;

        orientation = image.GetPropertyItem(ExifOrientationTagId).Value[0];

        if (orientation >= 1 && orientation <= 8)
        {
            switch (orientation)
            {
                case 2:
                    image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipX);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipX);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipX);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
                    break;
                case 7:
                    image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipX);
                    break;
                case 8:
                    image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone);
                    break;
            }

            image.RemovePropertyItem(ExifOrientationTagId);
        }
    }
}
```